# Spinnaker Automated Canary Analysis results in either 0 or 100 score nothing in between

Tags: spinnaker, canary-deployment

I am using Spinnaker/Kayenta for canary analysis. When canary stage runs, it either results in giving 0 or 100 score and nothing in between.

Is this is expected behavior??
How is the scoring done??

Looking at the pattern, seems like if the
Run Canary# fails because of genuine reason ['Canary score of previous interval(doesn't matter whether you have intervals or not) in less than marginal score.']. The Aggregate Canary Results phase never runs. Example snapshot below. It just produces a score of 0.

[image]

[image]

Steps to Reproduce:

- Set up a canary pipeline in spinnaker.
- Set it fail during canary analysis.

Additional Details:

When Run Canary# phase is successful. It executes the Aggregate Canary Results phase and produces a score of 100.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found out it was configuration that was causing Kayenta to terminate the canary build and not perform the Aggregate Canary Results phase.

> Criticality: Fail the canary if this metric fails

option was toggled on. It should be off to get the score.

[image]